# How to construct org.jooq.Result for unit testing

Tags: java, jooq

I am writing unit tests for fetching records from Oracle DB using JOOQ library and I need to mock data returned by `DSLContext`'s `fetch()` function. How can I create sample `Result<Record>` to be returned by mocked function? I googled it for few hours and could not find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use JOOQ's own mock API. Here are the official [docs](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/tools/jdbc-mocking/#N2207B)

You probably want to end up with something like that:

```
final MockDataProvider myMockProvider = new MockDataProvider() {
    @Override
    public MockResult[] execute(final MockExecuteContext context) throws SQLException {
        final DSLContext context = DSL.using(SQLDialect.ORACLE);
        final Result<Record> resultRecord = context.newResult(YOUR_TABLE_HERE);

        // customize your record with needed fields

        resultRecord.add(context.newRecord(YOUR_TABLE_HERE));

        return new MockResult[] { new MockResult(1, resultRecord) };
    }
};

final DSLContext mockedDSL = DSL.using(new MockConnection(myMockProvider), SQLDialect.ORACLE);

// here you go with your tests
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue, and I didn't want to have a `MockDataProvider`, as I was testing something else than the DAO. Therefore, I created a trivial function in order to convert a `Record` (or multiple) into a `Result<T>`.

Note that this is in Kotlin, but it should be easy to translate this into Java:

```
val jooq = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)

fun <T : Record> result(table: TableImpl<T>, vararg data: T): Result<T> {
    return jooq.newResult(table).apply { addAll(data) }
}
```

Which then can be used as follows:

```
result(TABLE_NAME, <a record>, <another record>)
```

And records can just be created using their constructors.